# What is best way to retrieve a table of data from a website?

Tags: php, html, dom, curl

Need to get a table from a website into my program

I started by using curl in cygwin to download the website - however it did not include the table

so looked into other means and found this post on

using php and curl to get a table

[Can I use cURL to grab a html table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242761/can-i-use-curl-to-grab-a-html-table)

I can inspect the table on the website with chrome inspect and see the 
class and table name
[image: http://prntscr.com/1m633g]

but not sure where to go from here, is Curl the best option? is there a DOM reader for HTML? what would be the easiest?

Here is the actual website where i am grabbing the data
http://www.trackinfo.com/dog.jsp?runnername=AMF%20SOUL%20SINGER

Comment: If curling the webpage did not include the table, is the table added by javascript?

Comment: how would I be able to figure out if it was added by JS?

Comment: Get the page with javascript disabled in your browser

Comment: interesting... disabled javascript and it doesn't show up, however they have page numbers and if I click on a page number it shows just the table data -> http://prntscr.com/1m66gv  then click page number -> http://prntscr.com/1m66jl

Comment: if I save that table that shows up it saves as this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/524410/dog-racelines.jsp.htm

Comment: `This website is intended for PERSONAL, NON-COMMERCIAL use only. This material may not be published, broadcast, rewritten or redistributed in any form. `

Comment: yup personal use .... thanks?